# Imagick: Issues reading file on Windows 64bit EasyPHP

Tags: windows, imagemagick, imagick

I'm having a lot of difficulty working with PHP's Imagick class, it doesn't seem to want to read images regardless to the method I use.

## Method 1

```
$handle = fopen('http://ima.gs/Placeholder-400x200.png', 'rb'); // Sample image
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageFile($handle);
$img->resizeImage(128, 128, 0, 0);
$img->writeImage(ROOT . DS . 'foo.png');
```

This gives me the Internal Error *"Unable to read image from the filehandle"*

## Method 2 (Ideal Method)

```
$img = new Imagick(ROOT . DS . '00053141.jpg'); // Image does exist
$img->resizeImage(128, 128, 0, 0);
$img->writeImage(ROOT . DS . 'foo.jpg');
```

This gives me the Internal Error *"no decode delegate for this image format `D:\Work\DittoCake\00053141.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550"*

## Configure List Results

You can see my delegates and configuration details here: http://cl.ly/image/1j2z1H072K41/Image%202014-10-22%20at%209.35.28%20AM.png

## Command line convert results

```
convert 00053141.jpg -set colorspace RGB 00053141_rgb.jpg
```

This worked successfully and can confirm that the image mode was changed from CMKY to RGB when checking in Photoshop. (My last resort is to use shell_exec but I'd prefer not to)

I have a feeling this may be because I'm running it on Windows, my main goal in using this is just to convert any image from CMKY to RGB, resizing / changing image type is already covered in my application.

Comment: What happens if you use PHP's `system()` function to run `convert 00053141.jpg -resize 128x128 foo.jpg`?

Comment: When I use system with the following command: convert D:\Work\DittoCake\00053141.jpg -resize 128x128 D:\Work\DittoCake\foo.jpg it does not work, but if I type the command into a cmd window it does work.

Comment: "It doesnt work" is not that helpful :-) What happens if you do `system("convert -version")`? I suspect 2 things. 1. Your PHP.INI file may be wrong and not point to correct ImageMagick with JPEG delegates. 2. Your PATH may be wrong inside PHP making your program actually run Windows' CONVERT.EXE that changes filesystem types.

Comment: It looks like you're correct, it's not using the same version from within system(). http://cl.ly/image/1U2R2J2G312A - I uninstalled the older version and it's now picking it up, I will retest some of these snippets I suspect they will work now. Thanks!